# Convert dataframe with 2 columns into series

Tags: python, time-series

I have a dataframe named `df` with index being the `date` and im trying to convert it into a Series.

```
date                price      sales
2012-01-22          4200         0
```

I tried

```
pd.Series(df['price', 'sales'], index=df.index)
```

but it returns an error. May I know how can I overcome it?

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible. A Series is a one-dimensional array-like object containing a sequence of values (of
similar types to NumPy types) and an associated array of data labels, called its index.

Answer (score 0):

try `df[['price', 'sales']].iloc[0]`.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': pd.Timestamp('2012-01-22'), 'price':4200, 'sales': 0}])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
print(df)

series = df[['price', 'sales']].iloc[0]
print(series)
```

output:

```
            price  sales
date
2012-01-22   4200      0
price    4200
sales       0
Name: 2012-01-22 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single row and want to convert to series you can use [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
s = df.squeeze() # or df.squeeze(0)
```

Output:

```
price    4200
sales       0
Name: 2012-01-22 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

Else, many options:

```
df.iloc[0]

df.loc['2012-01-22']

df.loc['2012-01-22', [['price', 'sales']]]

df.loc[df.index[0], [['price', 'sales']]]
```

Comment: `df.T['2012-01-22']` Could be another one to add to the list ~